# How can i create a certain format in moment?

Tags: node.js, momentjs

i am trying to change the output of a moment format to look like the standard output in morgan except that it uses my Timezone. my morgan time part looks like this

**Wed, 10 Apr 2019 05:02:31 GMT**

i would like it to be the same except to display time in PST

Comment: Did you check moment documentation? It should help you through this

Comment: Yes but it does not show how to simply set the name of time ZONE i can set the GMT offset like this morgan().format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS Z')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var myDate = moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z');
```

the above actually creates the exact thing i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment to create a specific format like this:

```
moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
```

That will output the current time of the server/machine you are on into the format you are looking for, except for the timezone part. There is an additional moment-timezone package to use for timezones. This may be a good starting point for you on the timezone part based on the docs:

```
moment().tz('Etc/GMT+1').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ZZ')
```

https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Moment Js [document](https://momentjs.com/) says you can use moment.format() to get the format you want it, and for your case it will be the one below:

`moment().format('dddd Do MMM YYYY h:mm:ss a');`